# Chek just updated photo permission on Facebook

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using this code to upload a photo on the Facebook user wall but the result dictionary return to me only photoid and postid, i need to know the permission level of the post that i have just share (during sharing process in native app the user can select Public,friends,only me...), There a way to know this permission?

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"",  @"message", nil];
 [params setObject:Picture forKey:@"source"];


[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                            parameters:params
                            HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                         id result,
                                         NSError *error)
{
   if (error)
   {
      //showing an alert for failure


   }
   else
   {
      //showing an alert for success



      NSString *phoId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result valueForKey:@"id"]];
      NSString *PostId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result valueForKey:@"post_id"]];





   }

}];
```

Comment: Can you not set the desired permissions?

Comment: I don't think that i can force a permission during sharing, but tell me if there is a way that i don't know

Comment: _“i need to know the permission level of the post”_ – why would you “need” that? You are not allowed to reward people for posting anything, and not allowed to “demand” they use a certain privacy level either.

Comment: "i need to know" for my application logic. After a share action the app behaviour change if the user share with public or only me permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do another Graph API Call using the post id of the photo you have just uploaded. The specific field you want to ask for is called 'privacy'. This field is an object. One of its properties is 'value', which can be one of the following:

- Everyone
- All Friends
- Friends of Friends
- Self
- Custom

From this, you can check the privacy people have specified on your post and adjust accordingly.

More info here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post